# Unable to add vNet peering to nested ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create an ARM template which creates 2 resource groups, and then deploys vNets and creates a peering between them. The vNet peering resource in the template is not working. I keep getting the same error and I believe it's because i'm trying to create a peering with a VNET which is in a different VNET/Resource group than the one i'm deploying into.

I am using nested templates to deploy into separate resource groups.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/Microsoft.Resources.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "VNet name"
            }
        },
        "vnetAddressPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Address prefix"
            }
        },
        "DMZResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "resource group for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "HUBResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "resource group for HUB environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZvnet": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "VNet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZvnetAddressPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "DMZ VNet Address prefix"
            }
        },
        "DMZFESubnet1Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet1 for DMZ environment. This is the Front-End subnet"
            }
        },
        "DMZBESubnet2Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet1 for DMZ environment. This is the Back-End subnet"
            }
        },
        "DMZNSG": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "NSG for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZFEsubnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Front-End subnet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZBEsubnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Back-End subnet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "subnet1Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 1 prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet1Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 1 Name"
            }
        },
        "subnet2Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 2 Prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet2Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 2 Name"
            }
        },
        "subnet3Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 3 Prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet3Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 3 Name"
            }
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "location": "West Europe",
        "HUBvNettoDMZvNet": "[concat(parameters('VNetName'), '-', parameters('DMZvnet'))]",
        "DMZvNettoHUBvNet": "[concat(parameters('DMZvnet'), '-', parameters('VNetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('DMZResourceGroup')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('HUBResourceGroup')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "hubtemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('Hubresourcegroup')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('HUBResourceGroup'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentversion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
                            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet2Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet3Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet3Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('dmzvnet'), '/peered-to-', parameters('vnetname'))]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
                            "location": "[variables('location')]",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('VNetName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
                                "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
                                "allowGatewayTransit": true,
                                "useRemoteGateways": true,
                                "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                                    "id": "/subscriptions/d01e22a2-bdb3-4c7a-92a2-613cc0dc1f30/resourceGroups/dmz-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dmz-vnet"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
                            "location": "[variables('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "securityRules": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "allow-rdp",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "allow rdp",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "10.0.1.0",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 110,
                                            "direction": "Inbound"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "allow-smb",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "allow smb",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "445",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "10.0.2.0",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 112,
                                            "direction": "Inbound"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "dmztemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('DMZresourcegroup')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('DMZResourceGroup'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentversion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "name": "[parameters('DMZvNet')]",
                            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "[parameters('DMZvNetaddressPrefix')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('DMZFEsubnetName')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DMZFESubnet1Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('DMZBEsubnetName')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DMZBESubnet2Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error I am receiving

> New-AzureRmDeployment : 16:13:36 - Resource 
>   Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings
>   'DMZ-VNET/peered-to-HUB-VNET'  failed with message '{   "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceNotFound",
>       "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DMZ-VNET' under resource  group
>   'HUB-RG' was not found."   } }' At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmDeployment -Name $jobname -location $location -TemplatePar ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implement
>   ation.NewAzureDeploymentCmdlet

Comment: can you share the whole deal? why is your vnet id hardcoded?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Sorry it's because I wanted to make sure it was working before adding the parameters in. I have edited the code to include all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you can amend `"outputs": {}` everywhere, they dont really add anything useful, only clatter the template :). ok, there's just too much stuff going on here, to get into details of everything, unfortunately, here's a working template, you can diff yours and figure out what is wrong. if you need some questions answered, just get back to me here.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/Microsoft.Resources.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VNetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "vnetname"
            }
        },
        "vnetAddressPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Address prefix"
            }
        },
        "DMZResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "resource group for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "HUBResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "resource group for HUB environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZvnet": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "VNet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZvnetAddressPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "DMZ VNet Address prefix"
            }
        },
        "DMZFESubnet1Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet1 for DMZ environment. This is the Front-End subnet"
            }
        },
        "DMZBESubnet2Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet1 for DMZ environment. This is the Back-End subnet"
            }
        },
        "DMZNSG": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "NSG for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZFEsubnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Front-End subnet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "DMZBEsubnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Back-End subnet for DMZ environment"
            }
        },
        "subnet1Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 1 prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet1Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 1 Name"
            }
        },
        "subnet2Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 2 Prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet2Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 2 Name"
            }
        },
        "subnet3Prefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 3 Prefix"
            }
        },
        "subnet3Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 3 Name"
            }
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "location": "West Europe",
        "HUBvNettoDMZvNet": "[concat(parameters('VNetName'), '-', parameters('DMZvnet'))]",
        "DMZvNettoHUBvNet": "[concat(parameters('DMZvnet'), '-', parameters('VNetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('DMZResourceGroup')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('HUBResourceGroup')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "hubtemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('Hubresourcegroup')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('HUBResourceGroup'))]",
                "dmztemplate"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentversion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
                            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet2Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnet3Name')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet3Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName'), '/peered-to-', parameters('vnetname'))]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
                            "location": "[variables('location')]",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('VNetName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
                                "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
                                "allowGatewayTransit": true,
                                "useRemoteGateways": false,
                                "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                                    "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('DMZresourcegroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('DMZvNet'))]"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
                            "location": "[variables('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "securityRules": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "allow-rdp",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "allow rdp",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "10.0.1.0",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 110,
                                            "direction": "Inbound"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "allow-smb",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "allow smb",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "445",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "10.0.2.0",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 112,
                                            "direction": "Inbound"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "dmztemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('DMZresourcegroup')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('DMZResourceGroup'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentversion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "name": "[parameters('DMZvNet')]",
                            "location": "[variables('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "[parameters('DMZvNetaddressPrefix')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('DMZFEsubnetName')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DMZFESubnet1Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('DMZBEsubnetName')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('DMZBESubnet2Prefix')]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

resourceId() in subscription level deployments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription#using-template-functions

ps. I'm sure you need peerings on both vnets.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately this didn't solve it :(. I added the "dmztemplate" as per your suggestion. I understand what you're saying, although I've got a dependson function before it does the peering. It makes sure both VNETS are there before it does the peering. Also, it's still complaining about the DMZ-VNET being there, so I think it's something to do with

 remoteVirtualNetwork": {
       "id": "/subscriptions/d01e22a2-bdb3-4c7a-92a2-613cc0dc1f30/resourceGroups/dmz-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dmz-vnet"
 }
as that's the only place it's referenced.

Comment: It may be because i'm referencing a VNET that's in a different resource group. That's why I added the 

"id": "/subscriptions/d01e22a2-bdb3-4c7a-92a2-613cc0dc1f30/resourceGroups/dmz-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dmz-vnet" }

to reference the whole subscription and resource groups etc.

Comment: I will try this in the morning. Thanks for your quick replies! What else did you change or was it just the VNET ID?

Comment: it was vnetId, peering resource name, dependsOn, `"useRemoteGateways": false,`. thats probably it, but you should just diff the templates. i might have forgotten something.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it :). Marked as correct answer.